# Nuget pack won't install

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I am having problems install some Elmah packages in my project(if I make a new solution these packages work)

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'elmah (= 1.2.0.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'elmah.corelibrary (= 1.2)'.
Successfully installed 'elmah.corelibrary 1.2.1'.
Successfully installed 'elmah 1.2.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'Elmah.MVC 1.3.2'.
Successfully added 'elmah.corelibrary 1.2.1' to WebUIProject.
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Successfully uninstalled 'elmah 1.2.0.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'elmah.corelibrary 1.2.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

anyone seen this before? I have version 1.6 for nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your web.config file for any anomalies. This exception means that there was problem reading XML file.

Comment: What am I looking for? I mean the web.config must be valid as I can run the project so I am not sure what kind of errors I am looking for.

Comment: Neither do I. ;-) try copying web.config file from brand new project and see if you can install elmah package.